# Use of moved value: `game`

Tags: rust, slint

I'm creating a game of 2048 with a UI using Slint. I have a ownership (?) issue when I have 2 different actions that can modify my game. They cannot be called at the same time (but the compiler does not know that). I don't find this kind of issue on the documentation.

```
mod board;

use board::Board;
use slint::{ModelRc, SharedString, Weak};

slint::include_modules!();

fn update_app(ui: AppWindow, game: &Board) {
    ...
}

fn main() -> Result<(), slint::PlatformError> {
    let mut game = Board::new(32);

    let ui = AppWindow::new()?;
    let ui_handle = ui.as_weak();

    update_app(ui_handle.unwrap(), &game);

    ui.on_restart(move |seed| {
        println!("Restarting with seed: {}", seed);

        game.restart(seed.parse().unwrap());    // if commented, OK
        update_app(ui_handle.unwrap(), &game);  // if commented, OK
    });

    ui.on_play(move |direction| {  // otherwise error here: use of moved value: `game` value used here after move
        println!("Playing with direction: {:?}", direction);

        game.apply_action(direction as u8);
        update_app(ui_handle.unwrap(), &game);
    });

    ui.run()
}
```

What is the standard approach for this kind of problem? ChatGPT proposed to use a "Reference Counted" but I could not make it work.

Comment: The problem is that you cannot `move` the game object into both closures, as only **one** can *own* it. You could copy a reference to both closures, but it won't work if either `restart` or `apply_action` needs a mutable reference, as you can only have one mutable or multiple immutable references to an object.

So you need to share it between the two closures. ChatGPT is correct, you need to have it reference counted, but since I don't know how Slint works, it might be that you need a multi-threaded synchronization structure. It depends on how they've defined their API.

Comment: Yes both references needs to be mutable as both actions are modifying the underlying board of the game. I've read some docs about Rc and I have to give a try to RefCell instead as Rc (that does not allow mutable borrow). I'll give it another try in few hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution has been found using a Reference Counted for the game and duplicate the weak references to the ui (1 per action)

```
mod board;

use std::{cell::RefCell, rc::Rc};

use board::Board;
use slint::{ModelRc, SharedString};

slint::include_modules!();

fn update_app(ui: AppWindow, game: Rc<RefCell<Board>>) {
    ...
}

fn main() -> Result<(), slint::PlatformError> {
    let game = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Board::new(32)));
    let ui = AppWindow::new()?;

    let ui_handle = ui.as_weak();
    let ui_handle_on_play = ui.as_weak();
    let ui_handle_on_restart = ui.as_weak();

    let game_on_restart = Rc::clone(&game);
    let game_on_play = Rc::clone(&game);

    ui.on_restart(move |seed| {
        game_on_restart.borrow_mut().restart(seed.parse().unwrap());
        update_app(game_on_restart.unwrap(), Rc::clone(&game_on_restart));
    });

    ui.on_play(move |direction| {
        game_on_play.borrow_mut().apply_action(direction as u8);
        update_app(ui_handle_on_play.unwrap(), Rc::clone(&game_on_play));
    });

    // setup and run the UI
    update_app(ui_handle1.unwrap(), Rc::clone(&game));
    ui.run()?;
    Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ui` is already a Rc. You can do `let ui_restart = ui_handle.clone();` before the `on_restart` and then use that in that move closure instead of `ui_handle`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the issue is more on the ''game'' object that can be modified by both methods. The Ui part seems to be working with ui_handle.unwrap().